# access jquery children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div style="float: right; margin-top: 15px; " class=" class1">

    <div style="min-width: 50px; min-height: 29px; opacity: 0.5; " class=" sub1_class">
        <div style="height: 29px; background-image: none; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " class=" sub2_class">

            <div style="height: 39px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; zoom: 1; cursor: pointer; background-image: url('images/new'); margin-top: 1px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; " class=" sub3_class" unselectable="on">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to access the children elements and change its css of the above dom structure. How do I do it. I am learning jquery.
I have assigned `class1` class to a variable.
`myclass=document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0];`

And I need to change the css of class names `sub2_class` and `sub3_class`.
How do I do this??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you don't need to use `getElementsByClassName`, use jQuery's selectors.

```
$( '.class1 .sub2_class' ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

(By the way, consider styling elements using classes instead of inline CSS.)

Answer (score 1):

The below code would do that,

```
$("div.class1").find("div.sub1_class").addClass("new_css_class_name");
$("div.class1").find("div.sub2_class").addClass("new_css_class_name");
```

you could also use removeClass, if you want to delete the existing css class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a litte example:

```
<style>
my-class { color: red}
</style>

<div id="id-parent">
 <span id="id-child-1">hello</span> <span id="id-child-2">world</span>
</div>

<script>
$("#id-parent>*").addClass("my-class"); //you make hello world to red
</script>
```